# How to Pass bitmap QR code to ole object (picture) crystal report c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I am trying to make a QR code in crystal reports so I make code in windows form that makes the QR code
then I have to pass the QR code to my crystal reports throw this form 
any idea, please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a UFL that saves the resulting QR code as an image, so you can load it on the fly via the Graphic Location expression of a dummy image object on the report.

That's the approach I used when implementing [this function](https://www.milletsoftware.com/CUT_Light_User_Manual/#uflBarcodeQR()%20or%20uflBBarcodeQR()).

This has the advantage of having no dependency on a QR Code font. If such a dependency doesn't bother you, there are several solutions using that approach. Here is [one such solution](https://support.idautomation.com/QR-Code/How-to-create-QR-Code-barcodes-in-Crystal-Reports/_2119).